# Table dataSource changes my original array when i dont want - Angular Mat-Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, datasource, mat-table

I have a problem, when i modify a cell using an input in my table from dataSource (mat-table) my original array previously saved change too. Someone can explain me or tell me where is my error or concept error or why my original array also changes as the table and input is linked to **dataSource** data and not to **users** array, or that is what I believe. I want preserve the original array to restore if user dont save changes
 **sorry for my bad english**

> > user.component.html

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" fxFlex *ngIf="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex>
      Nombre y Apellido
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client; let i = index" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex>
      <div *ngIf="client._id !== editable">
        {{ client.name + ' ' + client.surname }}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="client._id === editable">
        <mat-form-field fxFlex style="margin-right: 7px;">
          <input type="text" matInput placeholder="nombre" [(ngModel)]="client.name" name="name" />
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex class="m-r-20">
          <input type="text" matInput placeholder="apellido" [(ngModel)]="client.surname" name="surname" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="100px">
      Edit
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client, let i = index" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="100px">
      <div *ngIf="client._id !== editable">
        <button matTooltip="Editar cliente" (click)="setEditable(client._id, i); $event.stopPropagation()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-sm btn-success" type="button" style="margin-right: 2px">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-account-edit"></i>
                </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" matTooltip="Eliminar cliente" (click)="deleteClient(client._id, i); $event.stopPropagation()">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="client._id === editable">
        <button matTooltip="Editar cliente" (click)="updateUser(client); $event.stopPropagation()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-sm b-green" type="button" style="margin-right: 2px">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-check"></i>
                </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm b-red" matTooltip="Cancelar" (click)="setEditable(null, i); $event.stopPropagation()">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-close"></i>
                </button>
      </div>

    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

> > user.component.ts

```js
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  public users: UserModel[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'options'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserModel>;
  public editable = null;
  public roles: Role[] =  [
    { value: 'CLIENT_ROLE', viewValue: 'Cliente' },
    { value: 'USER_ROLE', viewValue: 'Usuario' },
    { value: 'ADMIN_ROLE', viewValue: 'Administrador' },
  ];
  constructor(
    private _user: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._user.getUsers().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.users = resp.users;
      this.dataSource = resp.users;
    }, err => {
      console.log('Error', err);
    });
  }
  setEditable(value: string, i: number) {
    if (!value) {
      this.dataSource = this.users;
    }
    this.editable = value;
  }

}

export interface Role {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}
```

## If i change client.name my dataSource change but also users changes.

Only way i can save my original array is if i store in localStorage and its works but i need understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you set datasource and users to the same response, making it the same instance. Try and make them unique by assigning a copy instead.

this.users = [...resp.users];
this.dataSource = [...resp.users];

Just a guess. And I am on my phone, so I can't really check

Comment: didn't work :/ if u can help me later ill appreciate